# Vimscript get what command to be executed

Tags: vim

I want my Vimscript to know if a specific command(tabmove) is going to be executed now, either by reading a predefined register or invoking a function.

I've searched all the information I can get from google or vim document. But found nothing.

```
if current_command == 'tabmove*'
    dowhat
endif
```

For now I still don't figure out an effective way to make this, can someone Vim expert offer some advice?

Comment: You need an [autocmd](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd.txt). Either you need a specific autocommand or generic, catch-all autocommand. In the latter case you can check what autocommand is in progress using [v:event](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#v%3Aevent) variable.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement well. You want to know which cmd is going to be executed? when it would be happen? you type `:somecommand` then press `enter`? or what?

Comment: Thanks Kent&phd, I am writing a plugin that maintains a Vim tabpage jumplist, which can help user to jump back to previously visited tabpage. as you know, the tabmove command will move the tabpage yet no triggering any event, then the jumplist will stay unchanged. I just want to know what event will trigger when user execute tabmove command.

Answer (score 0):

In vimscript, [autocmd](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd.txt) is the best way to make a trigger for one event.

Please check [Autocommands](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html) for more details about autocmd. If there are too many operations you want to use, please read [Autocommand Groups](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html).

Before define your own events, please check the list of [autocmd-events](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-events) bulit in vim.

Maybe you should try how to define CursorMoved in a tabpage???

```
autocmd CursorMoved call fucntab()

func fucntab()
    if (tabpage)
        "do your work??
endfunc
```

PS. [tabpage in vim manual](https://vimhelp.org/tabpage.txt.html#tabpage.txt)

Comment: Hi Lex, thanks for this knowledge, I think you miss the point, I know autocmd works like a hooker function to listen to the event triggered by VIM. But I just want to know what event is triggered by a specific operation. Anyway, still great thanks, I have found my way to achieve what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no hook for command execution; because the hook itself executes commands, this could quickly result in endless recursion, and it probably would be really slow.

If you want to hook certain commands when used *interactively* (vs. executed in Vimscript by a plugin or mapping), you can override the command with a custom `:command`. Users would have to remember to use the (starting with an uppercase letter) version, or you could force this through a command-line mode mapping or a plugin like [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](https://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746) (I maintain an [extended fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/cmdalias.vim).)

Alternatively, you could also hook into the command-line via `:cmap <CR>` and parse out the command yourself.

---

But I think what you're looking for is not a generic hook, but rather a particular trigger. For most common uses, there's a corresponding event that you can hook into via `:autocmd`; see [`:help autocommand-events`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocommand-event) for the whole list. In particular, there's [`TabEnter`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#TabEnter) and [`TabLeave`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#TabLeave). If you hook into both, you can determine both the originating and destination tab page easily.

Comment: > "There's no hook for command execution; because the hook itself executes commands, this could quickly result in endless recursion".  You may be surprised to learn that computer science has solutions for these kinds of problems. For instance, the hook could be controlled by an enable flag, whose value is saved, reset and restored around the execution of the hook.